# Zorn's Lemma and Posets

Tags: set-theory

If $A$ is a poset in which every chain has an upperbound in $A$ ($a$ be any element in $A$). There exists at least one maximal element $m$ in $A$ such that $m \geq a$.

Whats the difference between this and Zorn's Lemma?

Comment: yes i meant a<= m. Sorry

Answer (score 4):

I suppose that you meant to say that for every $a\in A$ there is a maximal element larger than $a$ itself.

Zorn's lemma only guarantees us a maximal element. But perhaps there is only one? Perhaps some elements are not below any maximal element?

This slight variant of Zorn's lemma tells us that above any element there is a maximal one. This is a stronger statement, at first sight. Of course it proves Zorn's lemma, but as it turns out the opposite is true as well.

Assume Zorn's lemma, and let $A$ is a partially ordered set in which every chain has an upper bound. Given $a\in A$ we define $C_a=\{x\in A\mid a\leq x\}$, and we can show that $C_a$ with the restricted order is also a partial order in which every chain is bounded. Zorn's lemma assures that there is $m\in C_a$ which is maximal, but it is not hard to verify that $m$ is maximal in $A$ as well, and therefore any $a\in A$ lies below a maximal element.

So while there is no *actual* difference, the statements are different. Whereas Zorn's lemma only assures us that *some* maximal element exists, this version assures us that every $a\in A$ lies below one.

Comment: Does it have something to do with lattice?

Comment: No, a lattice is a particular kind of a partial order, and often lattices are required to have a maximum. This is a general statement about a broader family of partially ordered sets.

Comment: Do you have any links to the fullproof of this question?

Comment: What do you mean? Proof that Zorn's Lemma implies the variant, or the other way around? Or something else?

Comment: I showed that Ca is a poset and Ca has at least one maximal element. Can anyone help me how to show that every maximal element in Ca is also maximal in A?

Comment: Ahmed, if $m$ is a maximal element of $C_a$, and there was $n\in A$ such that $m\leq n$, then by transitivity $a\leq m\leq n$ we have $n\in C_a$. Since $m$ is maximal in $C_a$ we have that $m=n$ and therefore $m$ is maximal in $A$ as well.

Comment: wow it was that easy and here i was thinking some thing completely insane. Thanx Asaf. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Ahmed: No problem!

Comment: How can you tell that this maximal element is comparable wit $C_a$ elements?

Comment: @Meitar: The maximal element was taken *from* $C_a$, so it is necessarily satisfying $a\leq m$.